# I have a problem with %1 parameter passing and "=" sign

Tags: batch-file

I just wrote a `yt.bat` file which contains this:

```
echo %1
```

I'm calling it like this:

```
yt https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_yXqFA-Fxs
```

But it echoes back only this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v
```

Comment: You may need to actually `Call` it, but your issue is that it should be `yt "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_yXqFA-Fxs"`, then in `yt.bat` you'd use `%~1` instead of `%1`, if you didn't have a need for the surrounding doublequotes. Cmd is seeing the `=` character as a delimiter, this could also be fixed by escaping that character with a caret, i.e. `yt https://www.youtube.com/watch?v^=V_yXqFA-Fxs`, but I'd certainly not recommend that over using the doublequotes.

Comment: It's very unconvenient, youtube-dl works without any need for escaping. Do I need to write a simple python script?

Comment: do `%*` instead of `%1` - that takes the whole parameters as a string as it is.

Comment: @woopwoop399 Open a command prompt window, run `cmd /?` and read the output help, especially the last paragraph on last help page explaining that argument strings containing a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~<|>`` require surrounding quotes. In your case `cmd.exe` interprets the equal sign outside a double quoted argument string as argument separator like normal space, horizontal tab, comma or OEM encoded no-break space which are interpreted also as argument separators by `cmd.exe` except within a double quoted argument string.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo %*
```

That takes the whole parameters as a string as it is.